# Explicit calculation of residue fields in quadratic extensions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let's say we have a prime number $p=5,$ and we are interested in how the residue field $\mathcal{O}_k/P$ looks like, where $P$ lies over 5 in quadratic extension $k.$

I suppose this has to depend on whether 5 ramifies or not in the extension, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed with that.

Also, I saw somewhere that the residue field can be $\mathbb{F}_5$ or $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ but I'm also not sure how to get to that.

Edit: what about cubic extensions?

Comment: Hint: If $p$ ramifies in $K$ then $p\mathcal{O}_{K}=\mathfrak{p}^{2}$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Consider the norm of the ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ and for the ideal $p\mathcal{O}_{K}$, but $p\mathcal{O}_{K}$ has norm $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(p)=p^{2}=25.$ Since the norm is multiplicative we conclude that $N(\mathfrak{p})=\alpha$ and therefore $\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{p}$ has size $\alpha$. Do the same considerations when 5 is not ramified in $K$.

Comment: @YumekuiMath Thanks so much! This solves my problem. Is there anything similar that we can use for cubic fields? I mean, for quadratic extensions, we know how the norm looks like, so I guess the problem gets more complicated for cubic extensions? At least when they are not of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$, like here: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163995/what-is-the-norm-of-a-number-in-a-cubic-integer-ring)

Comment: We can use the same approach, though there are a bit more bookkeeping to do (because of more possibilities for primes lying above $p=5$). If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a cubic extension then $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(p)=p^{3}=5^{3}$ so any prime dividing the ideal $p\mathcal{O}_{K}$ must have norm dividing $5^{3}$, i.e. either $5$, $5^{2}$ or $5^{3}$. If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a cubic extension such that $p\mathcal{O}_{K}=\mathfrak{p}^{2}\mathfrak{q}$ then $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(p)=N(\mathfrak{p})^{2}\cdot N(\mathfrak{q})$, so $\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{p}\simeq\mathbb{F}_{5}$ by the same argument as before.