# Minimal polynomial, embedding, discriminant, and norm and trace

Tags: number-theory, minimal-polynomials

*Note: $r$ means sigma

For the number field K = Q($^3√7$)

a) Find the minimal polynomial of $^3√7$ over Q.

b) Find all three embeddings $r$: K-> C which fix Q point wise.

c) Compute the discriminant of $∆[1, ^3√7, ^3√7^2].$

d) Compute the norm and trace of $1 + 2(^3√7) − 5(^3√49)$.

I have followed my notes below:
$K=Q(^3√d)$, $d$ is cube-free! The minimal polynomial for $^3√d$ is $x^3 - d.$ So $Q(^3√d): Q = 3$ and the basis $[1, ^3√d, ^3√d^2]$

For a) I know that the minimal polynomial is $f(x) = x^3 -7$ for we set $x = ^3√7$.

For b) I think the three embeddings would be ${1,^3√7,^3√72}$ because of the notes above.

I'm not 100% sure on c) but I think the discriminant would be $1$ and I don't have a good grasp on finding the norm and trace on d).

Comment: The embeddings permute roots of $f$

Comment: Norm and trace are easy to compute, see examples at this site e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163995/what-is-the-norm-of-a-number-in-a-cubic-integer-ring?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have an easy notation, i will denote $a=\sqrt[3]7$. We will also need a primitive root of the unit of order $3$, i use $\zeta:=\zeta_3:=\frac 12(-1+i\sqrt 3)$.

Note the relations $\zeta^3=1$ and $1+\zeta+\zeta^2=0$, used in the sequel.

---

(a) The polynomial $f=x^3-7\in\Bbb Q[x]$ is zero in $a$, $f(a)=0$, so we have to show it is minimal, i.e. does not have (non-trivial) factors over the rationals. A factorization is only possible as product of two polynomials of degrees one and two. So it would have a linear factor, thus a root in $\Bbb Q$. This is not the case, since only $\pm 1/1$ and $\pm7/1$ (divisor of the free coefficient divided by divisor of the free coefficient) may be such roots. They aren't.

---

(b) A field morphism $\phi:K=\Bbb Q(a)\to\Bbb C$ is determined by the value $\alpha:=\phi(a)$.

So it maps $a\in K$ with $a^3=7$ into some $\alpha=\phi(a)$ with $\alpha^3=\phi(a)^3=\phi(a^3)=\phi(7)=7$. So $\alpha$ is one of the three roots $a$, $a\zeta$, $a\zeta^2$ of $f$ in $\Bbb C$. Each choice leads to a morphism.

---

(c) By definition:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta[1,a,a^2]
&=
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & a^2\\
1 &\zeta a & \zeta^2a^2\\
1 &\zeta^2 a & \zeta^4a^4\\
\end{bmatrix}^2
\\
&=
(1\cdot a\cdot a^2)^2\cdot
\det{} ^2
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 &\zeta  & \zeta^2\\
1 &\zeta^2  & \zeta\\
\end{bmatrix}}_{:=A}
\\
&=a^6 \cdot \det (A\cdot  A)\\
&=a^6 \cdot \det 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 3 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&=-a^6\cdot 3^3\\
&=-7^2\cdot 3^3\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(The zero entries in the matrix $A\cdot A$ as computed above come from $1+\zeta+\zeta^2=0$.)

Computer check:

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^3 - 7)
sage: K.discriminant()
-1323
sage: K.discriminant().factor()
-1 * 3^3 * 7^2
```

The field discriminant was computed w.r.t. the integral basis of $\mathcal O_K$

```
sage: K.OK().gens()
(1, a, a^2)
```

which is by chance the same as in the question.

---

(d) The given element and its "conjugates" are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
s &= 1 +2a - 5a^2\ ,\\
s' &= 1 +2\zeta a - 5\zeta^2 a^2\ ,\\
s'' &= 1 +2\zeta^2 a - 5\zeta a^2\ 
\end{aligned}
$$
Then the trace of $s$ is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Trace}_{K/\Bbb Q}(s) &= s+s'+s''\\
&=(1+1+1)+2a(1+\zeta+\zeta^2)-5a^2(1+\zeta+\zeta^2)\\
&=3+0+0\\
&=3\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And the norm is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Norm}_{K/\Bbb Q}(s) &= s\; s'\; s''\\
&=1^3+(2a)^3 +(-5a^2)^3 - 3\cdot 1\cdot 2a\cdot(-5a^2)\\
&=1 + 8\cdot 7-125\cdot 49 + 3\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 7\\
&=1+56-6125+210\\
&=-5858
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
I have used (a cousin of) the identity
$$(X+Y+Z)(X^2+Y^2+Z^2-XY-YZ-ZX)
\\
=X^3+Y^3+Z^3-3XYZ\ .$$
Computer check:

```
sage: s = 1 + 2*a - 5*a^2
sage: s.trace()
3
sage: s.norm()
-5858
```