# Verifying the Ring of integers of a cubic number field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification

I just finished (hope so) to compute the ring of integers of the cubic number field $\mathbb{F}:=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, with $\alpha$ a root of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+3x+20$. I just would like to be sure that my result is correct (otherwise hints are well accepted). We have easily that $[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{Q}]=3$ and that $\mathscr{B}=\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F}$ as  a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Another standard computation shows that $\Delta_{\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathscr{B})=-3^3\cdot19^2$. We have the square of the primes $3,19$ dividing our discriminant. I use the following theorem:

> If $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{F}$ with $\beta_i \in \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$ for all $i$, and if $\mathbb{Z}\beta_1+\cdots\mathbb{Z}\beta_n$ is not the full ring  of integers $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$, then there exist: a prime number $p$ with $p^2|\Delta(\beta_\,\dots,\beta_n)$ ; integers $m_i \in \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$, not all zero, such that $\frac{m_1\beta_1+ \cdots +m_n\beta_n}{p}$ is integral.

I have started with the prime $3$ and observed that the element $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\alpha+\frac{1}{3}\alpha^2$ is integral with minimal polynomial $g(x)=x^3-x^2-6x-12$. It follows that $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F} \subseteq\frac{1}{3}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3}+\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3}\alpha+\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3}\alpha^2$ (see here [Ring of integers of a cubic number field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297476/ring-of-integers-of-a-cubic-number-field)). Then i changed my basis into $\mathscr{B'}=\{1,\alpha,\zeta\}$, where i put $\zeta:=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\alpha+\frac{1}{3}\alpha^2$. Note that, now, $\Delta_{\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathscr{B'})=-3\cdot19^2$. I wish to find algebraic integers of the form $\frac{m_1+m_2\alpha+m_3\zeta}{19}$, with $0 \leq m_i\leq 18$ for all $i$. I claim this is impossible so that i can conclude that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\zeta]$. Note that an element of that type can be written as $\frac{m_1}{19}+\frac{m_3}{19\cdot3}+(\frac{m_2}{19}+\frac{m_3}{19\cdot3})\alpha+\frac{m_3}{19\cdot3}\alpha^2$. Because of what observed before, this element must equal a certain $\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{3}\alpha+\frac{c}{3}\alpha^2$ and this expression is unique, because of the structure of $\mathbb{Z}$-module of $\frac{1}{3}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. So, we would have $19\cdot 3 c=3m_3$ which implies $c=m_3=0$, because $0 \leq m_3\leq18$. An analogue argument shows that $m_1=m_2=0$. We don't have algebraic integers of that form, so that i can conclude. Actually we have $\Delta(\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F})=-3\cdot19^2$.

Comment: I had to change some imprecisions. Sorry for that. Now it looks it works.